# SQLite - what and how to?

Tags: database, linq, sqlite, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm all new to databases and I've heard that SQLite should be straight forward, but I kinda find that not to be the case.

I have a decent knowledge of C# and WPF and I'm trying to make a small personal project which I want to use in daily life. My idea is a program that manages receipts that I bring home.

I have two Models - Item and Receipt

```
    class Item
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public int ReceiptId { get; set; }
    }

    class Receipt
    {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Store { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    }
```

My corrent problem is that I've been caught in all the different SQLite "versions" available. I've found that there is ADO.NET and LINQ and some other sorts.. what does these different ones mean and is the programming syntax for each of them different and which would be most suitable for my case?

I'm developing in Visual Studio 2012 and I've managed to download the NuGet SQLite package that goes by the name "System.Data.SQLite (x86/x64)".

I want to create a database, create two tables with these object in them, but I have basicly no idea how to and searching google for a day or two has just me that more confused, since so many people use different syntaxes and most of the tutorials I've find relate to how people used the old "SQLite.dll". So what my question is, is how do I make a database that fits this program structure and how do I write, read, connect and disconnect to my database.

Comment: My humble opinion: using SQL express would be more straightforward in the beginning; you could avoid such issues. On the other hand, sqlite is a great database.

Comment: I don't see how that would help me in any way what so ever.  
  
First of, I don't know how to make a proper database (been fooling around with SQLite Administrator for some time, and I think I got it figured out, but far from sure.

Making queries for a database takes me nowhere too..  And I've been searching Google for at least 2-3 days now, without a proper solution.. First time ever that has happened to me.

Comment: A standalone database running its own server is more of a black-box that would allow basic connect-and-query usage. For example you could make a "proper database" in seconds. That's why I made that suggestion. Other than that, asking a more specific question might get you some help, the question is too broad.